# How to get rid of sweaty palms?

Tags: personal-care

I have a problem with sweaty palms. My palms always get sweaty and it is so irritating. Even in the winter season they always get sweaty. They are a problem for me, for example when I am writing my exams, all exams papers get wet spots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Drying Moist Hands

Use baby powder or another absorbent powder. One simple, direct, and fairly long-lasting way to get rid of unwanted hand moisture is simply to soak it up! You can do this a variety of ways, including applying an absorbent powder to your hands. Try pouring a thimble-sized amount of baby powder into your hands and spreading it around gently and evenly — you should immediately notice your hands feel cooler and dryer. Below are just a few more powders you may want to consider using:

- Chalk
- Talcum powder (note that talc can be poisonous if inhaled in
  significant quantities)
- Cornstarch (sometimes specifically used for this purpose in Hispanic
  countries, where it is called "maizena")
- Baking soda

> 2. Preventing Clammy Hands

Avoid greasy lotions. If you frequently use lotion on your hands, you may be inadvertently making them clammy. While some lotions (like those that contain antiperspirant chemicals) can actually help dry your hands out, others can make them more moist. Some substances, like petroleum jelly, can even make your hands extra wet or greasy. If you use lotion frequently, consider switching your go-to lotion for one that's lighter or one that's specifically formulated to have a drying effect.

https://www.wikihow.com/Get-Rid-of-Clammy-Hands